# How to assign vertex color to vertex color shader node?

Tags: scripting, materials

Hello I just recently learn about scripting in blender and I have problem attaching materials using script.

This is my code so far :

```
face = bpy.data.objects[nama]
face.scale =(0.00001,0.00001,0.00001)
face.rotation_euler.x = pi/2
face.location.z = 3.23

face.material.new(name = 'Skin')
bpy.data.materials["Skin"].node_tree.nodes["Vertex Color"].layer_name = "skin"
```

I try to copy the script from info when I do it via GUI and fail to do it on script.

The results that I want is like this, where the Base color change from default value into vertex color and select Col and then if possible named it into skin

[image: endresult]

Lemon's answer is almost correct but it has red label on vertex color and it makes my end result become dark

[image: problem]

Comment: What does 'nama' refer to ?

Comment: the name of 1 of my object. A .ply object that I have imported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> face.material.new(name = 'Skin')
> ```

'face' has no material property. And as the material is new, there is no vertex color in its node tree (and no node tree as it is).

You can:

```
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name = "Skin")
mat.use_nodes = True #Make so it has a node tree

#Add the vertex color node
vc = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeVertexColor')
#Assign its layer
vc.layer_name = "skin"
```

Now to link the vertex color output to the default principled shader:

```
#Get the shader
bsdf = mat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]
#Link the vertex color to the shader
mat.node_tree.links.new( vc.outputs[0], bsdf.inputs[0] )
```

Additionnaly, if you want to add it to the 'face' object:

```
face.data.materials.append(mat)
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code. It works until creating a new material but it doesn't change base color into using vertex color and to be honest I still don't quite understand what adding the vertex color node is. thanks

Comment: @Wanttobepro, what do you want to do or know exactly? I mean you said "what adding the vertex color node is." so? Could you give a hand made example of the node tree you want to have?

Comment: Sorry for being not clear. I hope the updated post will make it clear what I want

Comment: @Wanttobepro, ok, thank for your edit. Answer is updated.

Comment: I encounter a bit of problem, when I tried your code, my model turn into black and below the vertex color it has red label, you can check my updated post. When I command the vc.layer name it become perfect as what I wanted. So can you help me explain why?

Comment: Change the vertex color name. By default the name is 'Col' but as you wrote 'skin' in your question I changed it to 'skin'.

Comment: `vc.layer_name = "Col"`

Comment: I have tried using batFINGER answer and it doesn't have error, maybe we need to assign it with default name first then after that we can change it into different name. Anyway thanks for the help guys